# Simulating blocks jumping out of a box with Rigid Bodies

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

I need to recreate small blocks jumping out of a box and falling onto the ground.
I have at least 30 blocks. Therefore, I thought of avoiding manual keyframing and using Rigid Body sims.

The first issue I encounter is my block wobbling after colliding with the box interior.

[image]

The second question that I have is a bit more open:
Do you think this is an excellent approach to simulate blocks jumping out of a box ?

[image]

I am using a wind force field to create the initial impulse. Then, I keyframed the force influence to 0, activating the force placed on the floor with a negative value to attract the block towards a specific area.

Again, I am doing this cause I actually need to make 30 blocks jumping out of the box, and manually will be highly time-consuming.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I think if you move an invisible plane with rigid body passive and animated checked you can control the force a bit more. Like this:

[image]

[image]

even more boxes:

[image]

You can reduce the wobbling by using shape "box":

[image]